# Why is PHP's ftp_nlist not showing directories, only files?

Tags: php, ftp

I only see files, not directories when I call ftp_nlist(). What might I be doing wrong?

The view from FileZilla:

[image]

This code runs with no output. If I remove the conditional I get a list of the plain files sans directories.

```
$contents = ftp_nlist($ftp, '.'); 
foreach( $contents as $content ) {
    // directories don't have .s in them
    if( !strstr( $content, '.' ) ) {
        echo $content;
    }
}
```

Can supply further information if needed.

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557154/separate-file-directories-in-php

Comment: [Check this link](http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/php-directory-listing-script) for how to list directories.

Comment: @HeinA.Grønnestad, thanks. It seems that nlist doesn't actually list directories, as per Shankar's answer below, so I guess my best option  is ftp_rawlist?

Answer (score 2):

`ftp_nlist` returns only files. Not directories. [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php).

EDIT :

```
function ListOfFolder($folder_listarry,$conn_id){

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($folder_listarry); $i++) {
echo $folder_listarry[$i]."<br>";
if (is_dir($folder_listarry[$i]) === false)
{
   continue;
}
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $folder_listarry[$i]);
ListOfFolder($contents,$conn_id);
}

}
```

Comment: Ah! I was obviously misled by this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557154/separate-file-directories-in-php and this function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php#102969. Short of parsing ftp_rawlist, do I have another choice?

Comment: I dont think there is a direct route. Try the above code and check if it works out for you.

Comment: Looks good, thanks. Thing is, I need a $folder_listarry to loop through in the first place...

Comment: Yes exactly give a try and let know.

Comment: There is a link here similar to what you have asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110680/recursively-scan-directory-and-sub-directories-through-ftp-with-php

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use PHPs usual file/dir functions as [`opendir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) and related also, they support the [FTP file wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.ftp.php).